# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror

For my course in Python, I am creating a program that calculates the distance between two cities bases on their coordinates. It has worked and suddenly I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    distance(+1, 52, 22, +1, 4, 32, +1, 45, 30, -1, 73, 35)
  File "C:/Python27/flying_distances_1.py", line 26, in distance
    distance = Haversine(lat_1, lat_2, lon_1, lon_2) * 6367.0
  File "C:/Python27/flying_distances_1.py", line 4, in Haversine
    a_1 = math.sin((lat_2 - lat_1)/2) ** 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

This is the code that goes with it:

```
import math

def Haversine (lat_1, lat_2, lon_1, lon_2):
    a_1 = math.sin((lat_2 - lat_1)/2) ** 2
    a_2 = math.cos(lat_1) * math.cos(lat_2)
    a_3 = math.sin((lon_2-lon_1)/2) ** 2
    a_4 = a_1 + a_2 * a_3
    b = 1 - a_4
    d = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a_4), math.sqrt(b))

def conversion (sign, degrees, minutes):
    minutes_to_degrees = 1/60.0 * minutes
    total_degrees = minutes_to_degrees + degrees
    radians = total_degrees * 1/180.0 * math.pi
    total_radians = sign * radians

def distance (sign_lat_1, deg_lat_1, min_lat_1,
              sign_lon_1, deg_lon_1, min_lon_1,
              sign_lat_2, deg_lat_2, min_lat_2,
              sign_lon_2, deg_lon_2, min_lon_2):
    lat_1 = conversion(sign_lat_1, deg_lat_1, min_lat_1)
    lon_1 = conversion(sign_lon_1, deg_lon_1, min_lon_1)
    lat_2 = conversion(sign_lat_2, deg_lat_2, min_lat_2)
    lon_2 = conversion(sign_lon_2, deg_lon_2, min_lon_2)
    distance = Haversine(lat_1, lat_2, lon_1, lon_2) * 6367.0
    return distance
```

I have searched and searched but I can't seem to find the error that causes the aforementioned message in my code. It probably is something really small (and possibly quite stupid ;)), but the person that can find the error will help me back on track!

Comment: `conversion` returns `None`.

Comment: Well, great, but what solves it?

Comment: Make it return something that supports `-`.

Comment: What do you want lat_1, lon_1 to represent?

Comment: Of course! Thanks, this has shrunk my errors by two lines!

Comment: lat_1 and lon_1 represent the latitude and longitude of city 1, they are, as you can see, converted by 'conversion' first and then Haversine is called.

Answer (score 2):

There is no return statement in the `conversion` function. At the moment, the radians value is calculated then forgotten when the function finishes. If you want the value of `total_radians` to be accessed from outside the function, add

```
    return total_radians
```

as the last line of the conversion function.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. And, as I predicted, this was a really stupid mistake from my end.

Comment: If you feel this answer has helped you may upvote and accept.